# Filter QSqlTableModel using combobox input

Tags: qt, qml

In the example, I would like to filter the data contained in rsModel by making a selection in sectionComboBox.  In sectionComboBox, I display the NAME of a section, and would like to filter rsModel to entries with a matching SECTION_ID

```
ComboBox {
        id: sectionComboBox
        model: sectionModel
        textRole: "NAME"
        onCurrentTextChanged: rsModel.setQLFilter("SECTION_ID=" + ??)
    }
```

QLTableModel subclasses QSqlRelationalTableModel and implements setQLFilter

```
void QLSqlTableModel::setQLFilter(const QString filter){
  setFilter(filter);
```

}

Comment: You are using the signal `onCurrentTextChanged` so I guess your are looking for the property `currentText` ?

Comment: @koopajah currentText would yield the NAME of the current row in sectionModel.  However, I would like to update rsModel using the ID of the current row.

Comment: @onezeno > Then use `onCurrentIndexChanged` and `currentIndex`

Comment: @koopajah I'm actually trying to get the value of the ID column, rather than the index number.  It seems that with a ListModel I could do something like listModel.get(currentIndex).id....but I don't know how to do this with QSqlRelationalTableModel

Comment: @onezeno > Try to dump what you have in your model and search for the id you want : http://pastebin.com/NNpPv5dN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's code that seems to be working.  Please suggest any improvements you might see.

QLSqlTableModel.cpp (derived from QSqlRelationTableModel)

```
void QLSqlTableModel::setQLFilter(const QString & field, int value){
  QString tempString = field + QString::number(value);
  setFilter(tempString);
}


QVariant QLSqlTableModel::data(int row, int role) const {
    QModelIndex qmi;
    qmi = index(row, role, qmi);
    return data(qmi, role);
}
```

main.qml

```
ComboBox {
    id: sectionComboBox
    model: sectionModel
    textRole: "NAME"
    onCurrentIndexChanged: {
        rsModel.setQLFilter("SECTION_ID=", sectionModel.data(currentIndex, 0))
    }
}
```